# Mapbox geocoder only partially working in a get/create route. Why is my code not working properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mapbox

I am trying to add a mapbox geocoder to my get/create route.  I have an async function for the geocoder to get the coordinates of the location. The console log will tell me promise pending for the coordinates for my model but give me the correct corrdinates in the log from the mapbox geocode function log. From the log of full array. My code feels right but i just dont get why its not working? Here is my code:

```
async function geocoder() {
    try {
        let response = await geocodingClient
        .forwardGeocode({
            query: req.body.location,
            limit: 1
        })
        .send()
        var coordinates = response.body.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        req.body.coordinates = response.body.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        console.log(response.body.features[0].geometry.coordinates);
        return coordinates
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}




// get data from forum and add to post array
var home        = req.body.home;
var title       = req.body.title;
var location    = req.body.location;
var zipcode     = req.body.zipcode;
var coordinates = geocoder(req.body.location);
var dsc         = req.body.description;
var image       = req.body.image;
var endDate     = req.body.endDate
var author      = {
    id:           req.user._id,
    username:     req.user.username
};
var contactInfo = {
    phoneNumber:  formatPhoneNumber(req.body.phoneNumber),
    email:        req.body.email
}

var newHome = {
    data:           data, 
    title:          title,
    location:       location,
    zipcode:        zipcode,
    coordinates:    coordinates, 
    description:    dsc, 
    image:          image, 
    author:         author,
    contactInfo:    contactInfo,
    endDate:        endDate,
};
```

The console output is:

```
{ coordinates: [ Promise { <pending> } ],
  _id: id,
  service: '10001',
  title: 'Maimi',
  location: 'Miami, Fl',
  zipcode: '33101',
  description: 'Miami',
  image: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9R1N_ww10wE/maxresdefault.jpg',
  author: { id: id, username: 'username' },
  contactInfo: { phoneNumber: ‘phone', email: 'email' },
  endDate: 2019-12-20T05:00:00.000Z,
  created: 2018-10-16T15:54:23.943Z,
  __v: 0 }
[ -80.1937, 25.7743 ]
```